# Define systemd units in cloud-init

Tags: systemd, cloud-init

There is a way to define systemd units in cloud-init? I was thinking to define the files then write them under `/etc/system/systemd` dir. The issue is that I'm not sure if the system run them or I should run them manually in the `runcmd` section. Not sure even about the order